# how to execute crm book action via web api?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

CRM exposes [actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607600.aspx), and it allows you to execute them via Web API.

For example the following is the `WinOpportunity` action schema and API:

```
<Action Name="WinOpportunity">
  <Parameter Name="OpportunityClose" Type="mscrm.opportunityclose" Nullable="false" />
  <Parameter Name="Status" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
</Action>
```

And to execute this question, you would POST the following:

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/WinOpportunity HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0

{
 "Status": 3,
 "OpportunityClose": {
  "subject": "Won Opportunity",
  "opportunityid@odata.bind": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/opportunities(b3828ac8-917a-e511-80d2-00155d2a68d2)"
 }
}
```

*Is there a way to execute the BookRequest Action?*

In examining the CSDL schema, I found that this action is defined as:

```
<Action Name="Book">
<Parameter Name="Target" Type="mscrm.crmbaseentity" Nullable="false"/>
<Parameter Name="ReturnNotifications" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
<ReturnType Type="mscrm.BookResponse" Nullable="false"/>
</Action>
```

**What will the request look like for this Book action?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.bookrequest.aspx), the `BookRequest` message expects `Appointment` as `Target`. [Book](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt718079.aspx) action as well.

```
// Create the ActivityParty instance.
ActivityParty party = new ActivityParty
{
    PartyId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, userResponse.UserId)
};

// Create the appointment instance.
Appointment appointment = new Appointment
{
    Subject = "Test Appointment",
    Description = "Test Appointment created using the BookRequest Message.",
    ScheduledStart = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
    ScheduledEnd = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
    Location = "Office",
    RequiredAttendees = new ActivityParty[] { party },
    Organizer = new ActivityParty[] { party }                        
};                    

// Use the Book request message.
BookRequest book = new BookRequest
{
    Target = appointment
};
```

Referring [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607600.aspx#Specify%20entity%20parameter%20type), webapi request may look like this: (am using existing appointment record, still getting 400 Bad request)

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/Book HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0

{
 "Target": {
  "activityid": "59ae8258-4878-e511-80d4-00155d2a68d1",
  "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.appointment"
 }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt seem correct. "The property 'Subject' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.crmbaseentity' --- same with description, scheduledstatart etc...

Comment: ```The following example shows how to use this message. For this sample to work correctly, you must be connected to the server to get an IOrganizationService interface. For the complete sample, see the link later in this topic.```

Comment: am testing in CRM rest builder.. wait